# Button if statement shortcut

Tags: php, html

I have the buttons "YES", "NO", "RESCHEDULE", "CANCEL". I am trying to hide the button that is currently active to stop repetition. I'm looking for a shortcut since I keep repeating the buttons in each of my if else statement. I will just summarize my code for convenience.

`$rowOrder['scheduled']` is the current active button.

```
<?php if ($rowOrder['scheduled'] == 'YES') { ?>
  SHOW NO BUTTON;
  SHOW CANCEL BUTTON;
  SHOW RESCHEDULED BUTTON;
<?php } else if ($rowOrder['scheduled'] == 'NO') { ?>
  SHOW YES BUTTON;
  SHOW CANCEL BUTTON;
  SHOW RESCHEDULED BUTTON;
<?php } else if ($rowOrder['scheduled'] == 'RESCHEDULED') { ?>
  SHOW YES BUTTON;
  SHOW NO BUTTON;
  SHOW CANCEL BUTTON;
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Reverse the logic - `<?php if($rowOrder['scheduled'] != 'YES') { ?>SHOW YES BUTTON;<?php } ?>`, repeat for the next three buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// Store all buttons as array
$allButtons = [
    "YES" => 1, 
    "NO" => 1, 
    "RESCHEDULE" => 1, 
    "CANCEL" => 1,
];
// next - unset the key `$rowOrder['scheduled']` from this array:
unset($allButtons[$rowOrder['scheduled']]);
// iterate over rest of array and show buttons:
foreach ($allButtons as $type => $v) {
    // show button according to it's `$type`
}
```